# Take all the file structure but these directories

Tags: cp, file-copy

I want to copy an entire file structure (with thousands of files and hundreds of directories), it's a hierarchy of directories and there are those **node_modules** directory that I want to exclude from the copying process.

Is there a Unix command to copy from a directory and all of its files and sub-directories recursively with an option to say don't include the directories with the name `<name>` ?

Something like :

```
cp root/ rootCopy/ --except node_modules
```

?

If not, is there a simple way to do that from the command line without writing a bash or something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with `rsync` or `tar` command .

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672480/cp-command-should-ignore-some-files) post.

From [`rsync` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

```
    --exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
    --exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```

---

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'dir*' source/ destination/
```

Comment: I managed to transfer my workspace lightweighted thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Creepy method, but it works for me:

```
(find source|egrep -v "node_modules|^source/exact/node_plugin" && echo tmptarget)|xargs cp --parents
mv tmptarget/source target
```

Explanation if needed. `cp` works like this:

```
cp source1 source2 ... sourceN target
```

- So do the `find` to print your whole structure.
- Use `egrep` to exclude all unwanted branches. Make sure you have properly formed your pattern. Use `^` and full path if you would like to exclude exact branch, or just `node_modules` if you want to exclude all of them.
- printout the destination folder with `echo` command.
- Let `xargs` put all these lines to `cp` command for you
- `--parents` is needed to create parents folders, because we cant use `-r` option here, as it will mess everything on the target folder.
- And finally `mv` whole new structure to real target